# reload-on-show with angular masonry not working

Tags: angularjs, masonry

I have got a little photo app on the build to better understand angular but struggling to get masonary to reload itself when a tab is opened. I am using https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

So far i have a wall of photos, on one side my/(the users) photos, and on the other the users friends photos. Nothing too spectacular.

Everything works great except when i click to the second tab (the friends photo wall), masonry is not reloading.

https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry#user-content-reload-on-show
This states you simply need to add the attribute: reload-on-show  which will in turn reload the container when ng-show is called.

But it does not want to play ball.. instead they all site on top of each other. As far as i can tell i am appling the ng-show correctly.

The controller

```
 photoApp.controller('PhotoWall', ['$scope', '$http', '$log',
    function($scope, $http, $log) {
        /* Handle my photos */
        $http.get('/api/my-photos').success(function (data) {
            $scope.myPhotos = data;
        });
        $scope.$on('handleUpdateMyWall', function(event, obj) {
            $scope.myPhotos.unshift( obj );
            $scope.$apply();
        });

        /* Handle their photos */
        $http.get('/api/friends-photos').success(function (data) {
            $scope.friendsPhotos = data;
        });

        /* Handle the tabbed interface */
        $scope.showMyPhotos = true;
        $scope.showFriendsPhotos = false;
        $scope.show = {
            friendsPhotos: function(){
                $scope.showMyPhotos = false;
                $scope.showFriendsPhotos = true;
            },
            myPhotos: function(){
                $scope.showMyPhotos = true;
                $scope.showFriendsPhotos = false;
            }
        }

    }]);
```

The html

```
<section ng-controller="PhotoWall" class="photoWall">

    <ul id="cssmenu" class="nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="{active: showMyPhotos }">
            <a href ng-click="show.myPhotos()">My Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: showFriendsPhotos }">
            <a href ng-click="show.friendsPhotos()">Friends Photos</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div masonry reload-on-show ng-show="showMyPhotos">
        <div class="photo masonry-brick" ng-repeat="photo in myPhotos">
            <p class="title">{{ photo.title }}</p>
            <img src="{{photo.image}}">
            <p class="description">{{ photo.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div masonry reload-on-show ng-show="showFriendsPhotos">
        <div class="photo masonry-brick" ng-repeat="photo in friendsPhotos">
            <p class="photoer">{{ photo.photoer }}</p>
            <img src="{{photo.image}}">
            <p class="title">{{ photo.title }}</p>
            <p class="description">{{ photo.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. after much staring i have decide to cheat little instead by resetting the $scope content for each wall when the tab is clicked.. seeems to work ok.

```
photoApp.controller('PhotoWall', ['$scope', '$http', '$log',
    function($scope, $http, $log) {
        /* Handle my photos */
        $http.get('/api/my-photos').success(function (data) {
            $scope.myPhotos = data;
        });
        $scope.$on('handleUpdateMyWall', function(event, obj) {
            $scope.myPhotos.unshift( obj );
            $scope.$apply();
        });

        /* Handle their photos */
        $http.get('/api/friends-photos').success(function (data) {
            $scope.friendsPhotos = data;
        });

        /* Handle the tabbed interface */
        $scope.showMyPhotos = true;
        $scope.showFriendsPhotos = false;
        $scope.show = {
            friendsPhotos: function(){
                $scope.showMyPhotos = false;
                $scope.showFriendsPhotos = true;
                var tmp = $scope.friendsPhotos;
                $scope.friendsPhotos = [];
                $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.friendsPhotos = tmp;
                });
            },
            myPhotos: function(){
                $scope.showMyPhotos = true;
                $scope.showFriendsPhotos = false;
                var tmp = $scope.myPhotos;
                $scope.myPhotos = [];
                $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.myPhotos = tmp;
                });
            }
        }

    }]);
```